# Why can't I see the hidden textview behind my cardview after it animates and moves to left for a second?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-cardview, cardview

I am trying to show a message behind the CardView in the space that is created after the Cardview moves to left for a moment and then again make that text invisible after the Cardview comes back to its original position. I want this to happen when I click on imageIcon present in upper right corner of the cardview. Currently, my cardview does move to left for a second when I click on the imageIcon but no Textview message gets shown behind the cardview. Below is my code and the XML file .

item_image.xml

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardAnimals"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_cardview"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_imageview" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name1TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text1"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name2TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gemCount"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|top"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/purp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hiddenTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

ImageAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.visuallithuanian.adapter

import android.R
import android.animation.Animator
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.visuallithuanian.data.ImageInfo


class ImageAdapter(private val imageList: List<ImageInfo>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.imageView)
    val textView1: TextView = itemView.findViewById(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.name1TextView)
    val textView2: TextView = itemView.findViewById(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.name2TextView)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.layout.item_image, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = imageList[position]
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.imageId)
    holder.textView1.text = currentItem.name1
    holder.textView2.text = currentItem.name2

    val imageIcon =
        holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.gemCount)
    val cardAnimals =
        holder.itemView.findViewById<CardView>(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.cardAnimals)
    val textHidden =
        holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.hiddenTextView)


     //Code where the cardview moves to left and Textview gets shown behind it.
    imageIcon.setOnClickListener {
        val anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(cardAnimals, "translationX", -500f)
        anim.duration = 1000
        anim.start()
        anim.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                val anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(cardAnimals, "translationX", 0f)
                anim.duration = 1000
                anim.start()
                anim.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                        textHidden.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }

}
override fun getItemCount() = imageList.size
}
```

I have visibiliy values along with ObjectAnimator but the invisible text view just never get's visible after i click on icon im cardview. My animation works fine .

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with XML file. `HiddenTextView` is not behind of CardView. Here is the updated XML. Update parent LinearLayout with FrameLayout and then no need to hide visibility of `HiddenTextView`.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardAnimals"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp">

                <Inside Code Remain Same>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hiddenTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. Now its working :) would you tell me why FrameLayout works and not LinearLayout

Comment: LinearLayout is used for aligning views one by one vertically or horizontally. so that multiple child views can arrange accordingly. FrameLayout is used to load views one above another.

Comment: Okay and one more query ; is it possible to add gray background to space that gets left behind when my cardview moves to left ?

Comment: You can add background color to frame-layout

Comment: it's not coming, if I put a background colour in FrameLayout, its visible even before i. click on the image Icon